# SQL Server 2012 XP_DELETE_FILE is Missing

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have inherited an SQL Server 2012 database that has a stored procedure which references a master database stored procedure called `XP_DELETE_FILE`. The stored procedure is failing because the XP_DELETE_FILE is not present in the master database. It seems to be an undocumented procedure and I don't know where I can source it. Any suggestions on a how to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
F.

Comment: Try calling `sys.xp_delete_file` instead?

Comment: Or tell us how it is being called now.

Comment: exec master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0, N'', N'', N'2015'

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to access the system extended procedure using the dbo schema. This was changed some time ago to use the sys schema.

Change this:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_delete_file ...
```

To this:

```
EXEC master.sys.xp_delete_file ...
```